# Why don't I need to std::move to a std::bind'ed function?

Tags: c++, g++, c++11, rvalue-reference, stdbind

Let's say I have a function, taking an rvalue reference:

```
void whatever (std::unique_ptr<int>&&) {
    // Nothing!
}
```

... and I bind its one parameter to a placeholder.

```
auto f = std::bind(&whatever, _1);
```

I tried the invocations like this, and the result is the opposite of what I was expecting.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> nothing;
f(std::move(nothing));  // Fails to compile!
f(nothing);             // Works, but seems wrong!
```

Is this a compiler bug? Or, is the working invocation unsafe code? Or why is it that I don't have to `std::move` this pointer into the bound function?

The compile error with gcc4.4, by the way, is:

```
test.cxx:14: error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >&&)>) (std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >)'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get just the opposite results when using [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).

```
std::unique_ptr<int> nothing;
f(std::move(nothing));  // Works!
f(nothing);             // Fails to compile!
```

I believe this is a gcc4.4 bug.  [func.bind.bind]/p10/b3 describes this case:

> - if the value `j` of `is_placeholder<TiD>::value` is not zero, the argument is `std::forward<Uj(uj)>` and its type `Vi` is `Uj&&`;

This may be fixed in a more recent gcc (I have no idea).

Comment: Interesting! I've got a more complicated case that I'm working on, and the result seems to depend on some side-effects of the surrounding code, as well.

Comment: Yep, seems to be fixed in GCC 4.7.

Comment: By the way, how do I find your reference to [func.bind.bind]/p10/b3? It doesn't google well.

Comment: @Andres: [func.bind.bind] is §20.8.9.1.2 of N3290. Download a copy of the standard, N3242 or the working draft, and look up General Utilities, Function Objects.

Comment: @AndresJaanTack: look for the newest draft of the c++11 standard you can find and search that document for [func.bind.bind]